# returning band members from musicbrainz

Tags: javascript, d3.js, musicbrainz

I've a reasonable amount of experience using javascript but never made a call to an external database, so this is new ground for me. I'm trying to return the members of a band as a json object from the Musicbrainz database. At the moment it doesn't matter which group so lets just say Nirvana as thats one of their examples. I've tried this:

```
var url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=url-rels&fmt=json";
  d3.json(url, function (json) {
    console.log(json)

  });
```

But that doesn't give me what I thought. I expected that the relationship array would contain the band members, start and end date etc, but thats not so. I get this back and the relationship array contains other data such as TV appearances

```
(index):19 Objectarea: Objectbegin_area: Objectcountry: "US"disambiguation: "90s US grunge band"end_area: nullgender: nullgender-id: nullid: "5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da"ipis: Array[0]isnis: Array[1]life-span: Objectname: "Nirvana"relations: Array[38]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object16: Object17: Object18: Object19: Object20: Object21: Object22: Object23: Object24: Object25: Object26: Object27: Object28: Object29: Object30: Object31: Object32: Object33: Object34: Object35: Object36: Object37: Objectlength: 38__proto__: Array[0]sort-name: "Nirvana"type: "Group"type-id: "e431f5f6-b5d2-343d-8b36-72607fffb74b"__proto__: Object
```

Could anyone help me out please or point me in the direction. I'm working in javascript.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Does that call actually return the bandmembers? Do you have any information on how that data should be returned to you, documentation or otherwise? I suspect that the answer may be in the "relations" array containing 38 objects, have you examined those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2), it looks like you need to add `artist-rels` to the subquery to get the band members, like this:

`http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=url-rels%20artist-rels&fmt=json`

Comment: This works better http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=artist-rels&fmt=json" It gives me an array of fourteen items in the relationships object all of which are band members except the last one, which is a tribute act. If anyone can refine this I'd appreciate it thanks

Comment: For ach realtionship you get a target-type and type. You are interested in the results with target-type="artist" and type="member of band". The tribute one would have type="tribute".

Answer (score 0):

this works a bit better:

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?inc=artist-rels&fmt=json"

It gives me 14 objects in the relationship array, all of which are band members except the last one. This appears to be a tribute act. If anyone can refine this I'd appreciate it. Thanks